# Частица "не" в неотрицающем смысле

Tags: частица

Сколько глобус не крути, невозможно нас найти.

Отчего в первом предложении стоит частица Не, а не Ни?

Comment: Это простой вопрос из школьной программы. У Вас есть свой вариант ответа?

Comment: "Неотрицающий смысл" лучше назвать утвердительным. Кроме того,  там пишется частица НИ. Так какая частица имеет утвердительное значение? Пожалуйста, отредактируйте название вопроса.